# Spamhouse PBL and smtp auth - LAN

Tags: email, email-server, spam

Have next setup:

[image]

I understand than the communication between email-clients and my email-server **over** the internet must use SMTP-AUTH. Otherwise, my mailserver can get into [Spamhouse PBL](http://www.spamhaus.org/pbl/) database.

The question is: MUST I use SMTP-AUTH in my LAN too?

- So the internal desktop computers should connect to my "internal mailserver" vith SMTP-AUTH?
- And when internal-mailserver sending email to Internet-mailserver must use SMTP-auth too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Spamhouse and similar databases the only thing that matters is how your mail server is secured against becoming a spam source, not how your clients work.

That means your analysis is ok: you will secure external access with autentication (IMAP and SMTP-AUTH) and encryption to prevent stolen credentials (IMAP and SMTP over TLS/SSL, and deny authentication to clients not using crypto).

Just keep in mind SMTP-AUTH does not mean the whole SMTP conversation is encrypted, it only means the SMTP session is authenticated with one of various methods (some are plaintext, some are simply obfuscated, some are encrypted). You should enable SSL/TLS on both IMAP and SMTP, after that you can even allow "plaintext" authentication because that plaintext will travel inside an SSL connection.

The other thing worth mentioning, is that you are not *required* to run protected protocols on your LAN, at least if you are 100% sure of the physical security of the latter (can you really be?), but it will be *easier* if you run everything equal.

Easier for server administration and easier for configuration of roaming clients (think notebooks, PDAs, smartphones).

Comment: Yes, can be. We are 4 friends on the company - and nobody want send spam. We have MAC controlled DHCP for desktop computers. We are using `OpenVPN` when connecting from "outside". But (as you correctly detected) - we have mobile phones what are connecting ALWAYS from "outside" (from the operator network) - and they are using TLS + IMAPS. For me is much-much easier *not* using SMTP auth in my 10.* (intranet) LAN and because it is NOT required - im happy now. :) Thank you for the answer - helped a lot.